# Firebase realtime database rules to edit only existing fields

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My database:

[image]

I want to set firebase rules where user can update existing tags value but not create new tags[image]

Comment: Doesn't work what's wrong
Line 4: No such method/property 'hasChildren'.

Comment: Don't add image duplicates, we see them just fine =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want the user to be able to update existing properties, and not create any new properties, that'd be:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "$uid": {
      ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"
      "$property": {
        ".validate": "data.exists()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So this rule validates that a property can only be written if there's already data for that property in the database.

---

If you only want the user to be able to write a `name` and `address`, and not any other properties, that'd be:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "$uid": {
      ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"
      "name": {
        ".validate": true
      },
      "address": {
        ".validate": true
      },
      "$other": {
        ".validate": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the above rules we allow writing the named `name` and `address` properties, and reject any other properties with a [wildcard capture rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#wildcard_capture_variables).