# firebase how can i restrict a write permission using validate to go though only a particular value only that is defined in the rules

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

i have a folder in the database user/user1 i want to write a name and phone to it i am testing this with
in rules playground

```
location = /user/user1
```

Data (JSON)

```
{
  "name": "value",
  "phone": "value"
}
```

rules

```
"user":{      
  "$uid":{  
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    ".validate" : "newData.child('name').exists() && newData.child('phone').exists() "         
  }  
}
```

This is working as i expected. If i put only the name, it will get denied. So that's good, and now i want also get denied if there is a 3rd value:

```
{
  "name": "value",
  "phone": "value",
  "data": "value"
}
```

Here is a security problem. If anyone adds a random value to this location, then i will get a large bill from firebase. I am afraid of this, or i am just getting paranoid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to disallow, which you can do by naming the allowed properties and then rejecting anything else with a so-called wildcard catch-all variable:

```
"user":{      
  "$uid":{  
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['name', 'phone'])", //  you must always have these
    "name": {
      ".validate": true //  you probably should validate the format here
    },
    "phone": {
      ".validate": true //  and you should validate the format here too
    },
    "$others": {
      ".validate": false //  other values are rejected
    }
  }  
}
```

Also see my answer to [Firebase realtime database rules to edit only existing fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68541741/firebase-realtime-database-rules-to-edit-only-existing-fields), which covers a similar care